# Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a continuous map such that $f(0)=f(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous map such that $f(0)=f(1) .$ Let $n \geq 2$
Show that there is some $x \in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) .$

My attempt. Assume $f(x)\neq f(x+1/n)$ for all $x$. Then either $f(x)<f(x+1/n)$ or $f(x)>f(x+1/n)$. WLOG, assume $f(x)<f(x+1/n)$. Then $f(0)

**So how can I get a contradiction? May you help?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WLOG you assumed that $f(x) < f\left(x+\frac1n\right)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Therefore we get

$$f(0) < f\left(\frac1n\right) < f\left(\frac2n\right) < \cdots < f\left(\frac{n-1}n\right) < f\left(\frac{n}n\right) = f(1)$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+\frac 1 n)$. If this continuous functions is never $0$ then it is always positive or always negative. Suppose it is always positive. Write $0=f(1)-f(0)$ as $[f(\frac  1 n) -f(0)]+[f(\frac  2 n)-f(\frac 1 n)]+...+[f(\frac {n-1} n)-f(1)]$. You get  a contradiction since each term is $<0$.

Similar argument works when $g(x) <0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Just added and subtracted some terms. For example, if $a<b<c$ then $f(c)-f(a)=[f(c)-f(b)]+[f(b)-f(a)]$ by adding and subtracting $f(b)$. @JamesEnsor

Comment: Okey, I understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
0 =f(0)-f(1)\\= \left[f(0)-f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]+\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\right]+\left[f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\right]\ldots+\left[f\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)-f\left(1\right)\right]
$$

You add and subtract the necessary pieces, but the terms without loss of generality are strictly negative.